# Is it worth sorting an array before using Array iterator methods?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say that I'm dealing with arrays that could have 100 or more elements, and that I constantly need to search for content in these arrays. Could sorting them improve the performance of using built-in Array iterator methods like `Array.prototype.forEach` or `Array.prototype.find`?

Comment: That depends entirely upon your use case... please elaborate further.

Comment: With ~100 elements you won't see any significant speed difference.

Comment: Better still is to use a `Map`.

Comment: @trincot Care to explain why do you think so? Anyways, wouldn't be better to use just simple `for` loop?

Comment: Do you mean something like in this case: [Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/4642212)?

Comment: @Kinduser I find that using built-in Array methods are simpler and takes less effort to write them. That's why I'm wondering if sorting arrays would help improve their performance.

Comment: Isn't `for` loop a build-in method? And just to precise - are you looking for simpler and easy-writable **or** fast with high performance solution?

Comment: @Kinduser, I'm talking about methods specific to the Array object in Javascript. Like forEach() or filter() or find() or shift().

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods_2

Comment: Then the `Array#forEach` solution is what you are looking for, imo. As far as I know, `forEach` doesn't return anything, that's why it works faster then `map`. But if I'm wrong, please correct me.

Comment: please add some data to get an idea, what are you looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.prototype.forEach` or `Array.prototype.find` are both iterating through the array. `Array.prototype.find` will be returning first element that satisfies the conditions in the callback function, otherwise it will also iterate the entire array. So sorting won't help you with these functions but it will help you if you are using something like a binary search function.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what basis you are requesting the item that you need. A preset order of lining the items might not help you with access time if you have a different logic per search like picking an item starting with a random character. You best use a `Map` object or a hash table i would say...